Fireball or fire spells vs. Sleet Storm
Sleet storm says:

Until the spell ends, freezing rain and sleet fall in a 20-foot-tall cylinder with a 40-foot radius centered on a point you choose within range. The area is heavily obscured, and exposed flames in the area are doused.
The ground in the area is covered with slick ice, making it difficult terrain. When a creature enters the spell’s area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there, it must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, it falls prone.
If a creature starts its turn in the spell's area and is concentrating on a spell, the creature must make a successful Constitution saving throw against your spell save DC or lose concentration.

Would Fireball, Wall of Fire or similar count as exposed flames? Basically, which spells should operate normally in its area and which would be disrupted?

You also could ask: Does the explosive heat of the Fireball influence the Sleet Storm (e.g. cancel the effect for the current round). 'Freezing rain and sleet' are not ignitable, but maybe they can be vaporized for the moment? Both effects (yours and mine) are not written in the spell description and therefore this situation falls under the regime of the DM.

It depends on whether the fire is an instant effect or has a duration
Sleet Storm says it douses exposed flames. But this language doesn't imply it would stop a fire from appearing at all. Only that it wouldn't last.
Hence instantaneous spells like fireball would still have their effect: Creatures in the area save, they take damage etc. This all happens in an instant and there is no rule either in fireball or sleet storm that would prevent such an instant effect. However, the fireball spell also states it can set fire to flammable objects. As this is an ongoing effect - literally exposed flames - then these would be immediately extinguished by the sleet storm
For longer duration spells such as wall of fire, its rather more ambiguous. By my own logic the spell would initially appear (and have the effect it states for creatures caught in the wall as it appears), but as it is now an ongoing effect - an exposed flame - it does seem as though sleet storm would douse the fire and effectively end the spell.
My evidence for this interpretation is that even the rules for underwater combat do not prevent fire-based spells from going off completely, they only state:

Creatures and objects that are fully immersed in water have resistance
to fire damage.

Sleet Storm doesn't even have any kind of caveat similar to this.

Check with your DM what that means
"Exposed1 flames in the area are doused" is what the spell says, and it does not make any exceptions regarding the kind of flame, magical or otherwise but doused is not a defined term, so we look at the dictionary. Dousing in regards to fire means (Oxford languages)

extinguish (a fire or light)

So those flames are extinguished. Both fireball and wall of fire create fire in the form of flames, fireball says it explicitly "blossoms with a low roar into an explosion of flame. [...] The fire spreads around corners", and  while wall of fire says "You create a wall of fire on a solid surface within range." and does not outright say it is made of flames, but I think it is safe to assume that it consists of flames.
You have two competing effects in that area, that of the fire spell, and that of sleet strom. The spellcasting rules say:

The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap.

What does one spell creating flames and one spell dousing any flames add together to? No flames. Based just on this, when you are in a sleet storm, you are protected from fireball's and wall of fire's effect.
However your DM can rule otherwise. They might decide that this applies only to mundane flames, or that wall of fire, as a higher level spell, is more powerful than sleet storm and can overcome it. Or that the dousing takes some time and the instant effect of an exploding fireball is exempt from that. Or even that the flames get extinguished, but not before having dealt their damage.
From a power perspective, I feel there is not much downside to allowing sleet storm to blank such effects. Sleet storm itself is 3rd level, as powerful by level as fireball, and it is a harmful effect. If you yourself would cast sleet strom on your area to protect yourself from fireballs, you also would blind yourself, and risk falling down on the slick ground. That seems not like a desirable tactic. And if you want to combine fireball and sleet storm to put the hurt on your opponents, at least narratively this seems questionable. Spells do what they say they do, but narratively one would expect that being drenched in icy rain offers some protection from fire, magical or otherwise.
Because doused is not a defined term, is is up to your DM how they interpret it works.

1 What does exposed mean? The spell is describing its effect as freezing rain and sleet fall, so the effect emanates from the top of the cylinder, and if you interpose a barrier that provides cover, it will not reach the area underneath. Having such a protective barrier could exempt flames in part of the sleet strom's area from its effects. If your fireball is going off under some shed roof or such that protects from the falling rain and sleet, or your wall of fire is underneath a similar construction, their flames are not exposed to sleet storm, and are not doused.

I agree with the logic. But...still following the basis of spells doing what they say they do...I would be inclined to rule differently with instantaneous effects vs non-instantaneous effects. i.e., the fireball is instantaneous and its spell description says everyone must make a save and suffer damage. It doesn't mention that it fails completely under snowy conditions. Though any secondary effects (the fireball setting fire to things) would be doused. I admit it's open to interpretation.

Yeah but description of spells is part of the spell, and it clearly said that fireball is an explosion of flame. @PJRZ

@PJRZ Then I propose you write that as your own answer, before someone else does.

That ruling is by RAW dubious at best, and most likely against RAI. A third level spell that last for a minute and impose difficult terrain, disrupt concentration and make people fall prone shouldn't be able to counter half of evocation spells as well, especially of the same or higher level.
